# Android app stores submission using google publishing API

Tags: google-play, google-play-developer-api

How to use the Google publishing API, which Google Play Developer Console that will enable me to automatically upload an APK to Google Play the first time? Is there any working sample for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use app release manager https://github.com/rakeshgirase/app-release-manager to publish APK file to Google Play store.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Developer Publishing API lets you upload and publish apps, and perform other publishing-related tasks. It provides functions similar to those available to a developer through the Developer Console, such as:

- Uploading new versions of an app
- Releasing apps, by assigning APKs to various Tracks (alpha, beta, staged rollout, or production)
- Creating and modifying Google Play Store listings, including localized text and graphics and multi-device screenshots

Those tasks are performed using the new [edits](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits/) functionality, which take a transactional approach to making changes; you bundle several changes into a single draft edit, then commit the changes all at once.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing

The Google Play Developer Publishing API Edits methods allow you to prepare a number of changes to your Google Play app, then deploy them all at once. You do this by creating an edit, which holds all the changes you want to make to the app. **You can only use this API to make changes to an existing app (that has at least one APK uploaded)**; thus, you will have to upload at least one APK through the Developer Console before you can use this API.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits

Comment: Is there any way to automate the first time upload process of new APK to google play developer console.

Comment: There is currently no official way for automatic upload of APKs to Google Play Developer Console. You might want to search on GitHub to find various 3rd-party scripts.

Comment: Are there any code samples for how to do this? I'm trying to use their .net libraries and C# in Visual Studio to create a command line app that will upload an app bundle to our internal test track. But I have no idea what to do to even get started.